# How to search for string from one column in other column and delete?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, replace, sql-delete

Let's say I have two columns in my MySQL database called `first` and `second`.

I want to search in `second` for the value of `first` an delete it.

Example:

First row: `first` is: `test`, `second` is: `Hello, this is a test!`

Expected result: `second` is: `Hello, this is a !`

I think it shouldn't be difficult but I don't know how to do.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: do you have to update the table?

Answer (score 1):

For querying, this should do it.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(second, first, '')
FROM your_table;
```

For updating:

```
UPDATE your_table SET second = REPLACE(second, first, '');
```

As mentioned by @Gordon in the comments below, add a where clause to do the update on the required rows only:

```
UPDATE your_table SET second = REPLACE(second, first, '')
WHERE second like concat('%', first, '%');
```

Comment: The `update` should probably have a `where` clause:  `where second like concat('%', first, '%')`.